# Magento 2 add ViewModel to product widget

Tags: magento2, widget, viewmodel

I use ViewModel for custom data in category product listing and everything working ok
but i need add ViewModel to widget with new products.

**Is it possible to add ViewModel to widget?**

Check my screenshot below 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a plugin on the widget Block to set a viewmodel. Here is an example of a ProductsList widget with an added viewmodel:

1. Create plugin and define it in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList">
        <plugin name="product_widget_add_viewmodel"
                type="StackX\CatalogWidget\Plugin\AddViewModelToProductWidget" />
    </type>
</config>
```

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace StackX\CatalogWidget\Plugin;

use Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList;

class AddViewModelToProductWidget
{
    private ViewModelClass $viewModel;

    //INSERT YOUR VIEWMODEL CLASS HERE
    public function __construct(ViewModelClass $viewModel) {
        $this->viewModel = $viewModel;
    }

    public function beforeToHtml(ProductsList $productsList): void
    {
        $productsList->setData('view_model', $this->viewModel);
    }
}
```

2. Use your viewmodel in the widget/products.phtml template:

```
$block->getViewModel();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to do this by conventional layout updates. I did it in a very roundabout way since I wast stuck.

1. I created a new block class and injected my VM into it.
2. I created a function in the new block to return my VM
3. I created a template override for the widget template.
   inside the override I did this call:
   $vm = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('YOUR_BLOCK_PATH')->youFunction();

Now this is obviously **not best practices** I just figured I would throw this out there. Another way would be to programmatically create the widget via layout update and add in your VM through the normal means. This would only affect that specific widget so I don't think that really helps you out. See this issue for an example of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38521803/how-to-add-widget-to-layout-in-magento-2

You could create your own widgets with custom classes/templates. This would probably be the best way.

Finally although this is also **not best practice**, you could make preferences for the widget block classes and add in your VM through dependency injection.

Here is a blog about doing a deeper dive into this: https://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/adding-viewmodels-to-widgets/